# Visual Studio emulator for Android: how to change keyboard language

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to find a way how to change language of software keyboard in VS emulator for Android. Now the language of input is English, and I want to change it to Russian.

Comment: try changing regional language and then have a look on keyboard : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394014(v=vs.105).aspx  ..let me know result

Comment: The article you provided can be applied to Windows Phone emulator, but not to Android emulator.

Comment: ohh sorry ..didnt notice that

Answer (score 0):

Solution (for example - 5" KitKat (4.4) API Level 19):
1. Open *Settings* in *Apps* tab and click *Language & input*
2. Select *Android Keyboard (AOSP)* settings
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQCpE.png)
3. Select *Input languages*
4. Uncheck *Use system language* (if it checked)
5. Check your languages in list below
6. Done.
Change the languages ​​on the virtual keyboard by tapping the globe icon:
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AidYz.png)